# Por qué me sale el error Unresolved compilation en Eclipse?

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Syntax error on token "new", ClassType expected after this token

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error está en que en la clase Principal no estas creando correctamente el objeto, la forma correcta es Student st = new Student();

Comment: Solo lenguajes geniales puede hacer `Student st = new()`, para java es necesario hacer lo que dice JFrame

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y adjuntes tu código como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Cuando respondas al comentario de alguien, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado.

Comment: Desde Java 10 puedes usar `var student = new Student();`